How do I get the user's webcam and process it on the server deployed webapp?
So I'm currently rebuilding my facial recognition app in flask and one thing that has stumped me is how to implement the function in the title into my program once I deploy it.
I've heard that cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) will not return anything when deployed on platforms like PA or Railway because opencv is trying to access the server's nonexistent camera.
Since that was the case I've been looking into capturing the user's webcam through JS and trying to feed them to OpenCV through websockets in base64, which this project demonstrated pretty well (https://github.com/tegarimansyah/opencv-streaming/blob/master/server/service/visual_manipulation.py). But I'm pretty confused on how to implement the visual manipulation part for two of my functions which required opencv (start(), and add()), the example of which I've linked above.
Any pointers and advice will really be appreciated as I'm sort of lost right now.
Here's the functions I'm trying to implement them in:
#### Attendance functions:
@app.route('/start',methods=['GET'])
def start():
    if 'face_recognition_model.pkl' not in os.listdir('static'):
        return render_template('second-static.html',totalreg=totalreg(),datetoday2=datetoday2,mess='There is no trained model in the static folder. Please add a new face to continue.')

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret = True
    while ret:
        ret,frame = cap.read()
        faces = extract_faces(frame)
        if faces is not None and len(faces) > 0:
            (x, y, w, h) = faces[0]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, ( x, y), (x+w, y+h), (139, 201, 145), 2)
            face = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            face_resized = cv2.resize(face, (50, 50))
            #face_gray = cv2.cvtColor(face_resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            face_flattened = face_resized.flatten().reshape(1, -1)
            identified_person = identify_face(face_flattened)[0]  # Assuming identify_face returns a list or array
            add_attendance(identified_person)
            cv2.putText(frame,f'{identified_person}',(x, y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(139, 201, 145),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow('Attendance',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"): # Q to quit
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    names,rolls,times,l = extract_attendance()    
    return render_template('second-static.html',names=names,rolls=rolls,times=times,l=l,totalreg=totalreg())


@app.route('/layout-static', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newusername = request.form['newusername']
        newuserid = request.form['newuserid']
        
        userimagefolder = 'static/faces/' + newusername + '_' + str(newuserid)
        if not os.path.isdir(userimagefolder):
            os.makedirs(userimagefolder)
        
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        i, j = 0, 0
        while 1:
            _, frame = cap.read()
            faces = extract_faces(frame) 
            
            for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                #cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (139, 201, 145), 2)
                image = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (139, 201, 145), 2)
                cv2.putText(image, f'So sanh: {i}/50', (x, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (139, 201, 145), 2)
                if j % 10 == 0:
                    name = newusername + '_' + str(i) + '.jpg'
                    cv2.imwrite(userimagefolder + '/' + name, frame[y:y+h, x:x+w])
                    i += 1
                j += 1
            
            if j == 500:
                break
            
            cv2.imshow('Adding new User', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):  # Q to quit
                break
        
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        
        print('Training Model')
        train_model()  
        
        names, rolls, times, l = extract_attendance()  
        
        return render_template('home/add_user.html', names=names, rolls=rolls, times=times, l=l, totalreg=totalreg())
    
    # Handle GET request or other cases
    names, rolls, times, l = [], [], [], 0  # Example data if no users registered yet
    return render_template('home/layout-static.html', names=names, rolls=rolls, times=times, l=l, totalreg=totalreg())


Please see if this thread may help you.
